# Is the Hungarian word "pirít" (to burn) a borrowing from Indo-European word for fire (*peh2wr)?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european, hungarian

I am wondering, is it possible that the Hungarian word *pirít* ‘to burn’ is a relatively-recent borrowing from an Indo-European language, from **peh₂wr-* ‘fire’? Obviously, it would have to happen after Proto-Finno-Ugric, that is, after the change from word-initial **p* to /f/ in Hungarian.

Comment: Is _pirít_ used for fire burning? From a quick glance at the dictionary, I thought it was more like "to fry".

Comment: Are you not supposed to show your own research first?

Comment: ‘Proto-Finno-Ugric’ is a vague and ambiguous term – it generally refers to either Proto-Uralic (not likely to have been spoken much later than around 2000 BCE) or the proto-language for the posited Finno-Ugric group within the Uralic languages (not likely to have been spoken much later than 1000 BCE – if it’s a valid grouping at all). The change of initial _*p_ to _f_ is Hungarian-only, not even shared with other Ugric languages (much less Finno-Ugric), so the loan would have to have happened after _Proto-Hungarian_ – probably after 700-1000 CE, which is a very different timeframe.